# Parsing JSON string in Java, why does it say "No value for ..."

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

So I am reading data from a sensors socket which looks like

```
{
    "d": {
        "temp_mC":0,
        "humidity_ppm":28430,
        "pressure_Pa":101242,
        "temp2_mC":32937,
        "co_mV":238,
        "no2_mV":1812,
        "light_Lux":0,
        "noise_dB":79,
        "cputemp_C":34,
        "battery_mV":3155,
        "ts":"1970-01-01T00:01:08Z"
    }
}
```

Which is stored is built by a `StringBuilder sb`.

I am not very familiar with parsing JSON strings (never done it before), but I want to get the `co_mV` and `no2_mV` data. I figured I did not have to use `JSONArray` or something. So I tried this

```
 JSONObject parser = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
 System.out.println(parser.getInt("co_mV"));
```

This returns

```
 "org.json.JSONException: No value for co_mV"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: obviously in json `{"d": { ... } }` there is no value for `co_mV` there is only `d` ... it's time to learn some json basics

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry. Thank your for the answer @Selvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data is held within a second JSON object called `d`, so you need to access `d` first before you access the rest of your data.

```
JSONObject parser = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
JSONObject d = parser.getJSONObject("d");
System.out.println(d.getInt("co_mV"));
System.out.println(d.getInt("no2_mV"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code:

```
JSONObject parser = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("d");
System.out.println(jsonObject .getInt("co_mV"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access to a child json param from parent one. Try:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
JSONObject dJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("d");
System.out.println(dJsonObject.getInt("co_mV"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
JSONObject parser = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
JSONObject parser_d = parser.getJSONObject("d");
System.out.println(parser_d.getInt("co_mV"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getString("d");
            String co_mV = String.valueOf(jsonObject1.getString("co_mV"));
            String no2_mV = String.valueOf(jsonObject1.getString("no2_mV"));
```